# Removing corrupt screen setting

Tags: interface

In the UI I for some reason have one Model and one Model.001 where the later on is corrupt. When selecting this screen the UI freezes and the only way to get out of it is to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> keys.

The blend file is binary so I can't edit it out manually. Is there a way to remove this?

Blender 2.68a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reload startup file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> (or any file, actually) not containing the corrupted screen layout. Reopen the problematic file but clear **Load UI** checkbox, under *Open Blender File* settings group in the file open dialog. Then save the file.

With **Load UI** unchecked, Blender will reuse UI settings from previously opened file, for the file to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a small Python console open for these types of fixes:

```
bpy.data.screens['CorruptScreenName'].user_clear()
```

Note you must first leave the corrupt screen, e.g CTRL-LEFTARROW. Alternately, bind a key to:

```
bpy.ops.screen.delete()
```

see: https://developer.blender.org/T36175